# Is there a WIN32 API equivalent to JAVA pack()?

Tags: java, windows, api, winapi, resize

My windows application needs to auto resize based on a variable number/size of child objects. The end user is not allowed to resize the window. I already know how to move/resize windows. I just need the best way to compact the parent window to fit the child objects.

I could calculate the new size in a number of ways, but if the WIN32 API already has a library for this like in java, I wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel. Can anyone point me in the right direction or confirm that the function does not exist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but no the Win32 API doesn't have such a thing. If you want anything like that, you'll pretty much need some sort of library on top of the API itself (or, of course, you can write it yourself).

Comment: @RHughes There is, however, a small set of [Rectangle Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162901.aspx), in particular [UnionRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145163.aspx) should reduce the amount of code you have to write yourself considerably.